# Does a JDBC ResultSet support pagination?

Tags: mysql, jdbc, resultset

Does JDBC ResultSet has pagination support? Or should I implement the internal pagination within my service by caching the result set. The reason why I am looking for such a solution is - I am not allowed to change the table structure. If allowed, I could have a autoincremental column and then fetch data using a clause on that column and limit.

Comment: Please ask only one question per question.

Comment: Alright. Done. Raised second question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63981002/jdbc-resultset-internal-mechanism-of-fetching-large-datasets).

Answer (score 3):

A `ResultSet` does not do pagination as such, however - depending on the database system and driver - the result may be fetched in batches. That is, the result set will request *fetchSize* rows from the server when it needs more rows.

This usually happens when `next()` is called and the result set has no rows available (though some implementations might even do it earlier as a performance optimization).

However, the MySQL Connector/J driver will by default fetch all rows in memory on execute. As documented on [JDBC API Implementation Notes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-reference-implementation-notes.html) under **Resultset**:

> By default, ResultSets are completely retrieved and stored in memory.
> In most cases this is the most efficient way to operate and, due to
> the design of the MySQL network protocol, is easier to implement. If
> you are working with ResultSets that have a large number of rows or
> large values and cannot allocate heap space in your JVM for the memory
> required, you can tell the driver to stream the results back one row
> at a time.
>
> To enable this functionality, create a `Statement` instance in the
> following manner:
>
> ```
> stmt = conn.createStatement(java.sql.ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY,
>               java.sql.ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY); 
> stmt.setFetchSize(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
> ```
>
> The combination of a forward-only, read-only result set, with a fetch
> size of `Integer.MIN_VALUE` serves as a signal to the driver to stream
> result sets row-by-row. After this, any result sets created with the
> statement will be retrieved row-by-row.
>
> *[.. but do read the caveat ..]*
>
> Another alternative is to use cursor-based streaming to retrieve a set
> number of rows each time. This can be done by setting the connection
> property `useCursorFetch` to true, and then calling `setFetchSize(int)`
> with `int` being the desired number of rows to be fetched each time:
>
> ```
> conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/?useCursorFetch=true", "user", "s3cr3t");
> stmt = conn.createStatement();
> stmt.setFetchSize(100);
> rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM your_table_here");
> ```

Comment: Great. I will dig deep into this. This seems to solve the issue I am facing. One more follow up doubt - When useCursorFetch is enabled, does that ensure that memory utilization is efficient in this case as compared to default retrieval of complete data and storing in memory? I understand that network wise latter is better as is gets all data on execute in one call. But in terms of memory, are the already read rows from resultset removed to make this feature more memory optimized or is it appended to the resultset in batches?

Comment: @Suman I don't normally use MySQL, but I would expect it will discard rows after `next()`. If you want to be sure, inspect the source of MySQL Connector/J or just try it.

Answer (score 0):

A result set is supposed to be consumed immediately *as fast as possible* since it's consuming resources in the database end as long as it's open. Even if some result sets can be navigated backwards, you shouldn't keep them open between page clicks in order to move rows forward or back. Those special result sets are for other purposes (processing rows in quirky orders) and not for pagination.

Now, you have two options:

- *Front end pagination*: the browser receives all the rows of the table, but shows only a few of them per page. The first page load can become slow, but then bo interaction is needed with the back end when moving between pages.
- *Back end pagination*: the browser receives only the rows you requested. This probably requires a "key set pagination" in the back end. Every time you move to the next or previous page a call to the back end is necessary.